# Верно ли согласование в моем предложении?

Tags: согласование

В предложении: «Берег пролива ощетинился пятью сотнями орудий, готов**ых** (**-ыми**) разгромить вражескую эскадру».

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***"...пятью сотнями орудий, готовЫХ..."***, потому что готовы орудия, а не сотни.

Answer (score 1):

> *Берег пролива ощетинился пятью сотнями орудий, готов**ых (-ыми)** разгромить вражескую эскадру».*

**Верны оба варианта.**

Похожие на рассматриваемый примеры есть у Розенталя в разделе «Причастные обороты».

**См. у Розенталя:**

> **§ 211. Причастные обороты**
>
> <…>
>
> В зависимости от значения возможно различное согласование причастий.
> Ср.: *Часть книг, **предназначенная** для выставки, уже получена*
> (получены  в с е  книги, предназначенные для выставки). – *Часть книг,
> **предназначенных** для выставки, уже получена* (получены   н е   в с е   книги, предназначенные для выставки).
> **Такие варианты согласования встречаются в тех случаях, когда причастный оборот определяет не отдельное слово, а словосочетание.**
> Ср. также: *Количество электроэнергии, **потребляемое…***
> (подчеркивается количественная сторона) – *Количество электроэнергии,
> **потребляемой…*** (характеризуется объект, о части которого идет речь); *Две тысячи рублей, **взятых** взаймы.* – *Десять тысяч рублей,
> **взятые** у сестры* (Л. Толстой).
>
> http://www.rosental-book.ru/styli_xlviii.html

Comment: Теперь понятно, почему звучат оба варианта.

Comment: @slava1947 С Новым годом, Слава! И — вечер добрый. Вы говорите о причастиях (и приводите ссылку о причастиях). Но ведь "готовый" — это прилагательное. (http://endic.ru/efremova/Gotovyj-17387.html)

Comment: И Вас, **Римма**, с Новым годом! И со старым Новым годом! Что же до «готовый» – Вы, конечно, правы: прилагательное. Но что поделаешь с тем, что Розенталь _неправильно_   озаглавил раздел с похожими на рассматриваемый примерами.  Ему надо было бы назвать этот раздел более общо: «Определительные обороты». Ну, или «Атрибутивные обороты»…

Answer (score 1):

Предпочтительный вариант:  ***Берег пролива ощетинился пятью сотнями орудий (каких?),  готовЫХ  разгромить вражескую эскадру.***

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

1. Сравним **другие варианты** согласования:

(1) *Берег пролива ощетинился **пятьюстами орудиями, готовыми** разгромить вражескую эскадру.* Согласование в Т.п.  всех трех слов.  Но: Книжная речь, точное указание числа, которое здесь не требуется.

(2)  *Берег пролива ощетинился **пятью сотнями  ОРУДИЙ, готовыми** разгромить вражескую эскадру.*

Здесь также согласование в Т.п.  трех слов, но между ними расположено слово в  Р.п., что напрягает слух пользователя, хотя оборот и **обособлен**.  Семантическое  объяснение  (ощетинился **всеми орудиями, готовыми**)   работает с натяжкой.

Оно требует от читателя дополнительного внимания, правильного прочтения, ознакомления со Справочником Розенталя и "особой настройки" сознания. Без такой подготовки сочетание "орудий, готовЫми" кажется странным.

2. Аналогичная ситуация **в Справочнике Розенталя**.  Пример с «частью книг» неубедительный, так как на слух разница воспринимается не сразу.

А оборот "десять тысяч рублей, взятые у сестры" (то есть "деньги, взятые у сестры") вообще кажется архаичным. Все-таки согласование близко расположенных слов по слуху представляется в современном языке более **актуальным**, чем «непроявленная» семантика без согласования.

Comment: А мне больше нравится вариант с "готовыми", потому что оно звучит более угрожающе, призывает к действию, а "готовых" — как нейтральная характеристика. И слух не напрягает. Так что зависит от задачи автора.

Comment: Угрожающе?  Может быть...  Здесь важно то, что оборот обособлен (причастный или определительный – это неважно), что позволяет выделить цельное числовой оборот. Пауза как бы смягчает несочетаемость окончаний

Comment: Вот здесь эта разница более ощущается: *У нас есть два десятка пушек, готовые/готовых выстрелить в любой момент.*

Comment: Да, здесь как-то не очень звучит...

Comment: Что не очень звучит? Тогда получается, что при согласовании с управляемым словом звучит как констатация, а с управляющим — есть что-то большее. Может, особенности родительного падежа.

Comment: Мне не нравится И.п. в обособленном  определении (готовые)

Comment: Мне тоже. Видимо нужно *что/которые готовы* в именительном. Но зато угроза больше.